# vertical columns without space (Continuous columns)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I don't want Breaks in columns, rather i want continuous columns...

**My code is:**

```
<div class="no-class" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 55px;float:left">

            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:20px;">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px">
                        <img class="no-class" style="width: 100%;" src="/2014060103422679450151db9-0851-4277-b59d-a23c34b7fa98.png"  alt="" />
                        image description<br />
                        description 2<br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:20px;">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px">
                        <img class="no-class" style="width: 100%;" src="/2014060103422679450151db9-0851-4277-b59d-a23c34b7fa98.png"  alt="" />                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:20px;">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px">
                        <img class="no-class" style="width: 100%;" src="/2014060103422679450151db9-0851-4277-b59d-a23c34b7fa98.png"  alt="" />                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:20px;">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px">
                        <img class="no-class" style="width: 100%;" src="/2014060103422679450151db9-0851-4277-b59d-a23c34b7fa98.png"  alt="" />                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:20px;">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px">
                        <img class="no-class" style="width: 100%;" src="/2014060103422679450151db9-0851-4277-b59d-a23c34b7fa98.png"  alt="" />                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:20px;">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px">
                        <img class="no-class" style="width: 100%;" src="/2014060103422679450151db9-0851-4277-b59d-a23c34b7fa98.png"  alt="" />                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:20px;">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px">
                        <img class="no-class" style="width: 100%;" src="/2014060103422679450151db9-0851-4277-b59d-a23c34b7fa98.png"  alt="" />                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by bread?

Comment: please explain the problem, put some image etc. or create a fiddle
jsfiddle.net

Comment: images are not allowed to me....

Comment: http://www.pixentral.com/hosted/1Dz8c01DBc1VESmFHCHtQ6PZP1_thumb.png

Answer (score 1):

If you want columns without space please remove the code

```
style="padding:20px;"
```

from every div that you have mentioned this code.

and if you want the column boarder seems single bar then use

```
style="margin-top:-1px;"
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

In the grid column layout of the bootstrap the `class="col-xs-3"` is for 3 columns of total 12 columns. You have added 7 div's with `class="col-xs-3"`. so you will get 4 columns in the first row and 3 columns in the second row. To resolve this. You can have `class="col-xs-2"` with six div's or `class="col-xs-3"` with 4 div's in the code.